# HTTP POST method fails

Tags: c#, http-post

I am a beginner for using WebRequest in C# and I am trying to using POST method to check my orders in Apple Online Store (https://secure2.store.apple.com/order/list).

I want to check a single order and found that I should use POST Method with Parameters: orderLookup-order-number(Order No) and orderLookup-order-user-info(My Apple Account).

I have tried to post these 2 parameters to https://secure1.store.apple.com/us/shop/order/json/single on https://www.hurl.it/ by:

POST TO: https://secure1.store.apple.com/us/shop/order/json/single

parameter1: orderLookup-order-number value: [Order No]

parameter2: orderLookup-order-user-info value: [Apple ID]

and successfully got a return. However when I do it in C#, I fail. Can anyone point out my mistakes please? My function is as follow.

```
bool TryPostMethodToGetHtmlText(string orderNo, string accountNo, out string htmlText)
{
    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://secure1.store.apple.com/us/shop/order/json/single");
    request.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:41.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/41.0";
    request.Method = "POST";
    request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
    var postData = "orderLookup-order-number=" + orderNo;
        postData += "&orderLookup-order-user-info=";
        postData += HttpUtility.UrlEncode(accountNo);
    byte[] postBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(postData);
    request.ContentLength = postBytes.Length;
    using (Stream st = request.GetRequestStream())
    {
        st.Write(postBytes, 0, postBytes.Length);
    }

    HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
    if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
    {
        Stream receiveStream = response.GetResponseStream();
        StreamReader readStream = null;

        if (response.CharacterSet == null)
        {
            readStream = new StreamReader(receiveStream);
        }
        else
        {
            readStream = new StreamReader(receiveStream, Encoding.GetEncoding(65001));
        }
        htmlText = readStream.ReadToEnd();
        response.Close();
        readStream.Close();
        return true;
    }
    htmlText = string.Empty;
    return false;
}
```

I got a 503 error when I wanted to get the HttpWebResponse. Thank you.

Comment: 503 indicates service unavailable response.

Comment: @gypsyCoder Thanks for your reply, but I can get a response when I don't pass any parameter for the POST Method

Comment: Best guess is authentication. The webrequest is not authenticated, so the server doesn't give you access to the data. Check the api on how to authenticate. (request + auth cookie? auth header in request?)

Comment: The data returned from just browsing to that url shows what seems like a HTTP redirect request, formatted as json data...

Comment: Double check if you are sending correct parameter names to the web api. See the documentation.

Comment: Also, the postData seems to be a query string parameter. I suggest append that to the API url and not write it to the request stream.

Comment: @Ephraim Irrelevant. That's how urlencoded transfer works. It's completely equivalent, but a good way to keep your code clean.

Comment: @TimEeckhaut Thanks for your reply, since I have tried posting the same things on https://www.hurl.it/ and got what I expected, so I don't think the problems is authentication.

Comment: @Nyerguds Thanks for your reply, you are right, I will get back json data which the url different from the url that I directly access without posting parameters

Comment: @TimEeckhaut I have not signed in. it is also work if I use chrome in incognito mode

Comment: Could you add the hurl request to the question?

Comment: @TimEeckhaut Done, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This solution is working.

```
        HttpWebRequest request  = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://secure1.store.apple.com/us/shop/order/json/single");

        request.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:41.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/41.0";
        request.Method = "POST";
        request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

        var postData = "orderLookup-order-number=" + orderNo;
        postData += "&orderLookup-order-user-info=";
        postData += HttpUtility.UrlEncode(accountNo);


        try
        {
            HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
            if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
            {
                Stream receiveStream = response.GetResponseStream();
                StreamReader readStream = null;

                if (response.CharacterSet == null)
                {
                    readStream = new StreamReader(receiveStream);
                }
                else
                {
                    readStream = new StreamReader(receiveStream, Encoding.GetEncoding(65001));
                }
                htmlText = readStream.ReadToEnd();
                response.Close();
                readStream.Close();
            }
            htmlText = string.Empty;
        }
        catch (WebException e)
        {
            htmlText = string.Empty;
        }

        HttpWebRequest requestForStream = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://secure1.store.apple.com/us/shop/order/json/single");
        requestForStream.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:41.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/41.0";
        requestForStream.Method = "POST";
        requestForStream.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

        byte[] postBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(postData);
        requestForStream.ContentLength = postBytes.Length;
        using (Stream st = requestForStream.GetRequestStream())
        {
            st.Write(postBytes, 0, postBytes.Length);
        }
```

Comment: Sorry, I dont know how your solution works, can you please explain? Thanks